# Autohotkey Alt+O remap

Tags: autohotkey, remapping

I want to create a remap script for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
The program for data entry that I use has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to close the dialog box for 'OK'

I would like to remap it to one of the following (because they are all on the left side of the keyboard)

zz or
xx or
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should set Alt+Z as equivalent to Alt+O:

```
!z::!o
```

You may wish to add in a stipulation that it only happens in the App you're using.  See [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) for details on doing that via `#IfWinActive` (in Remarks section).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this and doesn't work. Can you give me the code for Middle button = Alt +  O

Comment: huh.  that would be `MButton::!o` .  Just to clear, you put the previous one in a text file, save it with a `.ahk` extension, and double click it and it pops up in your system tray, but the new keyboard shortcut doesn't take effect? (also remember to kill or reload the previous running of the script if you make an edit and try again)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now both MButton::!o and !z::!o is working, I was editing a previous script and reloading, bit did not work, when I made a new .ahk from a text file it works. Thanks once again for the help.